# Why does my footer navigation become too wide at lower resolutions?

Tags: html, css, navigation, resolution

Why does my footer navigation become too wide at lower resolutions? I have the footer set-up with 100% width. When I switch to a resolution lower than 1920x1080
the "footer" and my "sitecontainer" expands it's width and becomes wider than 100% width. How do I fix this?

Website link: http://www.hgcarpentryandjoinery.com/MXJGTV/Test.html

Source code: view-source:http://www.hgcarpentryandjoinery.com/MXJGTV/Test.html

Comment: Please show us your code, not a link to your website. Thank you.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the `footer` is the problem. Have a look at this image: `<img style=" float:left: display:inline" src="images3/RightSpace.png" width="1146" height="58" alt="SidebarSpace">` which has a fixed width of 1146 pixels.

Comment: Thank you . I used a margin code instead of the image and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

This page has basic problems with RWD. Remove this part:

```
<img style=" float:left: display:inline" src="images3/RightSpace.png" width="1146" height="58" alt="SidebarSpace">
```

It's unnecessary.

Next - Do you want to center your div? Use:

```
margin:auto;
```